# Does Dreamworld for Pokemon BW or B2W2 still work?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

I am wondering does the dreamworld for pokemon black/white or black 2/ white 2 still work?

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this article](http://pokejungle.net/2013/07/01/dream-world-shutting-down-january-14th-tournament/) dated July 1, 2013:

> The Pokémon company decided that **keeping up the Dream World servers is too much of a cost**, or they just really want you to buy X&Y. Either way, starting from October 12th, the X&Y release date, new user accounts can’t be created anymore. On January 14th, the following services stop working:
>
> - You can’t play the mini-games to get the hidden ability Pokémon anymore. Putting new Pokémon to sleep will be blocked earlier, starting December 10th. You can still , wake your Pokémon up in your games, even when the service is down.

Comment: Ok thank you for helping me with the answer:3

Comment: @ShinyAronFruitBud you're welcome! If the answer is useful you can accept it :)

Comment: i dont know how to

Comment: @ShinyAronFruitBud there's a green tick next to the answer, you have to click it.